# How to to access images on main domain from subdomain

Tags: php, html

I have a main domain that users can upload images to which are then viewed in a slider so multiple images (sometimes up to 50) are loaded by the page on loading.  I am trying to access the same images on a subdomain but it isn't working very well.

If I use

```
<img src="<? echo 'http://www.mysite.co.uk/'.$row['imageLocation']; ?>">
```

the images load but it is very slow

If I use

```
<img src="<? echo '/home/myname/public_html/mysite.co.uk/'.$row['imageLocation']; ?>">
```

the images aren't displayed despite the path being correct.  If I use the same path for getting the images sizes (`getimagesize`) it returns the correct results so I'm sure the path is correct.

Comment: Are both URL's pointing to the same server?

Comment: You can't use the absolute path for the image `src` as it isn't publicly accessible. Your first example is your only current  option, the slow loading will be related to a different issue. You might want to look into using a CDN to improve image loading speed.

Comment: just test it like this, `<img src='/home/myname/public_html/mysite.co.uk/"<?=$row['imageLocation']?>"'>`

Comment: show what you have in  `getimagesize`

Comment: @ViktorSvensson yes, they are pointing to the same server

Comment: @user790454 list($width, $height) = getimagesize('/home/myname/public_html/mysite.co.uk/'.$row['imageLocation'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images arent shown because you echo the **path** to the user first, but not the file itself and then the users browser loads them asynchronously. He cannot access any parent directory from `mysite.co.uk` only child directories.

The PHP can load them because it runs on the server itself before it is returning anything.

What you could do is using  the `readfile()` function from PHP in an extra PHP file like `getimages.php` or just use the first solution, which cannot be improved in speed except you will change the image sizes, which might be your main problem here.

Comment: The images load fine on the main domain so I'm assuming that the speed issue is caused by the http request rather than accessing them directly

Comment: on your main domain you have the same http requests as well or not?

Comment: I just think its the number of images you are loading, as you said, up to 50. Have you tried loading 50 images directly from your main domain as well? In my understanding it should have the same loading time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  The path used for the images on the main domain is src='<? echo $row['imageLocation']; ?>, which is the same value pulled from the same db used by the subdomain

Comment: the loading time from the main domain is quick, it never has been an issue and still isn't, the images are jpegs about 70kb

Comment: I mean if you have any images in a webpage, the browser will automaticly load them. It does not matter from where they are because for every image the browser will send a new http or https request to the server, the images are on. The webpages the image tags are on, has no influence at all on the loading time of the images. Just the server (or domain) the images are on and the number of http requests, which run at the same time influence the loading time of the images.

Comment: It is probably the number of http requests you are senden, which is a lot apparantly.
You could bundle all your images into one and just send one image request. HTML and CSS will allow you to cut the image in parts afterwards again, this will significanly change the loading time.
Note: 50 times 70 kb is 3.5 megabytes which can be a lot depending on your internet speed.

Comment: so just to clarify there would be no benefit to using the direct path '/home/myname/public_html/mysite.co.uk/' rather than 'http://www.mysite.co.uk' ?

Comment: I used php imageMagician to resize the images to a 10th of the size as they were being uploaded which didn't make any difference but seeing as they were now the correct size I could stop using the getimagesize function at which point it worked just fine.  It seems using functions across domains doesn't work very well.  I accepted your answer because it at least taught me that I didn't need to worry about not using a http url for an image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly echo image file content, use this.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode('/home/myname/public_html/mysite.co.uk/'.$row['imageLocation']); ?>" />
```

Comment: @tatty27 `echo $row['imageLocation']` . what does it show?

Comment: upload/41/images/13935111181997113472/b0e420ab69d3.JPG

Comment: enter this command in terminal & make sure the path is correct  `ls -l /home/myname/public_html/mysite.co.uk/upload/41/images/13935111181997113472/b0e420ab69d3.JPG`

Comment: Do you have access to your server in which this website is hosted?

Comment: via cpanel, but I know the path is correct because I use the same path to get the image size etc